# How to edit payload request using extjs

Tags: extjs

I have filter:

```
store.filter([Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter', {
                        property : "firstName",
                        value : Ext.getCmp("firstName").getValue(),
                        root : 'data'
                    }), Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter', {
                        property : "lastName",
                        value : Ext.getCmp("lastName").getValue(),
                        root : 'data'
                    }), Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter', {
                        property : "gender",
                        value : "MALE",//Ext.getCmp("gender").getValue(),
                        root : 'data'
                    }), Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter', {
                        property : "ssn",
                        value : Ext.getCmp("ssn").getValue(),
                        root : 'data'
                    }), Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter', {
                        property : "dateOfBirth",
                        value : Ext.getCmp('dateOfBirthTo').getValue(),
                        root : 'data',
                        operator : "<"
                    })]);
```

which create this payload:

```
{..."filter":[{"property":"firstName","value":""},{"property":"lastName","value":""},{"property":"gender","value":"MALE"},{"property":"ssn","value":""},{"property":"dateOfBirth","value":"2013-05-22T00:00:00"}]}],...}
```

How I can change this payload ? I am using extdirectspring which need some additional parameters to create right filter. Instead of `{"property":"dateOfBirth","value":"2013-05-22T00:00:00"}`

I need:

`{"property":"dateOfBirth","value":"2013-05-22T00:00:00", "type":"date","operator":"lte"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried it, but just glancing quickly at the source code, it appears that you could override the encodeFilters() method of [Ext.data.proxy.Server](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server). Here's what it currently looks like:

```
encodeFilters: function(filters) {
    var min = [],
        length = filters.length,
        i = 0;

    for (; i < length; i++) {
        min[i] = {
            property: filters[i].property,
            value   : filters[i].value,
            // add your custom params here
        };
    }
    return this.applyEncoding(min);
}
```

In other words, when you create your filters, I believe you could add the custom config to those, and then with the override ensure they are included (if they exist) when the request is made.